# Efficiency physics problem

Tags: physics

84 An internal combustion engine consumes 1 gallon of diesel fuel per hour. It provides a
constant 10 hp. One gallon of diesel fuel has potential energy of about 115,000 Btu. Remember
that 1 hp × 42.44 = 1 Btu/min. What is the efficiency of the system?

**A.  22%** ***Answer***
B.  28%
C.  31%
D.  35%

How I approach this Since 1 gallon an hour is 115,000 then 10hp constant an hour is 424.4
There I use output/input x100. So $424.4/100000 * 100$ I got .42 I am confused in where I went wrong?

Comment: Haven't they got round to SI units in your part of the world?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: read *carefully* the following statement from the problem:

> Remember that $1$ hp × $42.44$ = 1 Btu/${\bf min.}\;$ [Bold-face mine.]

There are $60$ minutes in an hour.

Second: where are you making use of the information regarding potential energy of $\;115,000\;$ BTU?

Comment: Then is it 2546.4/115000*100 ?

Comment: Almost: you forgot this time around to multiply by $10$, for $10$ hp. With that, we get $$10\times 2546.4/115000 \times 100\% \approx 22\%$$

Comment: Perhaps, I'll be sure to address this on Wednesday as well.

Comment: See my edited comment: We forgot to multiply by the factor of $10$ hp

Comment: Ah..... I see the folly of my mistake.Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, Little Jon!  ;-)

Comment: Of course I shall now.

Comment: @amWhy: You are always helpful +1

Comment: @amWhy  Doesn't the part you high-lighted say that 42.4 HP is equal to 1 BTU/min?  That's not the case, but that's what I read: 1 HP, multiplied 42.4 times, equals 1 BTU/min...